# How connect to IMAP server in C#?

Tags: c#, email, connection, imap

How can I connect to a IMAP server in C# ?

*I prefer to not use a library !*

**I just need the connection** !

And for info, I searched on google, but I didn't find anything !

And I have no idea what to do !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/ and every other library does what you want; have a look at the source code of any of them.